# Unable to load AWS credentials when using Spark SQL through Beeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using Beeline connected to SparkSQL 1.3, I am trying to create a table that uses S3 data (using the s3a protocol):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mytable (...) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 's3a://mybucket/mydata';
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: FAILED: AmazonClientException Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain (state=,code=0)
```

I have the following environment variables set in `spark-env.sh`:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<my_access_key>
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<my_secret_key>
```

I know it's picking up this environment because the classpath is also set here, and it pulls in the Hadoop tools lib (which has the S3 connector). However, when I show the variables in beeline it says they are undefined:

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> set env:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID;
+------------------------------------+
|                                    |
+------------------------------------+
| env:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<undefined>  |
+------------------------------------+
1 row selected (0.112 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> set env:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;
+----------------------------------------+
|                                        |
+----------------------------------------+
| env:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<undefined>  |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row selected (0.009 seconds)
```

Setting `fs.s3a.access.key` and `fs.s3a.secret.key` also fails to have any effect:

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> set fs.s3a.access.key=<my_access_key>;
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> set fs.s3a.secret.key=<my_secret_key>;
```

Is there somewhere else I need to set this environment?

FWIW, I can successfully use `hadoop fs -ls s3a://mybucket/mydata` to list the files.

UPDATE:

I added the following to `hive-site.xml`:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
  <value>my_access_key</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
  <value>my_secret_key</value>
</property>
```

I can now create the table without error, but any attempt to query it results in this error:

```
Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: 
Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: 
Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to copy my `hdfs-site.xml` file (which contains the `fs.s3a.access.key` and `fs.s3a.secret.key` values) into `$SPARK_HOME/conf`.  Then it magically worked.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I was stuck with this issue for few hours but your approach works fine.